# What thes normal setup Serverless with S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Are there commonly used plugins that are used with serverless that supports integrating a single S3 bucket as static content, and having lambda functions to do the heavy lifting.

I'm thinking that by default content be served from a bucket(based on routes), and anything under /api be served by lambda.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **CloudFront**, it will handle the single domain topic (preventing CORS headaches), see more in this [Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html) in general, you are looking to configure CloudFront with multiple origins, with S3 being the default one.

Also you may want to put [API GW in front of lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-lambda-non-proxy-integration.html), to handle versioning, migration between versions, authentication and throttling.